# Shortcut for Rubymine fullscreen mode on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, fullscreen, rubymine

You can enter full-screen mode in Rubymine by navigating to `MENU > VIEW > ENTER FULL SCREEN`. Once in full-screen mode, moving your mouse to the top of the screen triggers the menu bar to dropdown, where you can once again navigate to `MENU > VIEW >` (now changed to) `EXIT FULL SCREEN`.

Does anyone know of a shortcut for this on Mac? I think there is one for OS X - not sure what it is off-hand, but can't find anyone anywhere for windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CTRL-COMMAND-F`

OS X KeyMap cheatsheet here: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/docs/RubyMine_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf